# Python: Why my module didn't instantiate an object via exec() statement?

Tags: python-3.x, exec, python-import, python-module, gridsearchcv

I created my own version of GridSearchCV module from sklearn.model_selection library. My version includes iterating through each parameter one by one instead of looking for all possible combinations. For example for a SVR model, if we have three parameters defined as follows:

```
   {
    'gamma' : np.arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.1),
    'C': np.arange(1, 10, 1), 
    'epsilon': np.arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.1)
    }
```

The algorithm would in the first turn find one best gamma coefficient (out of ten). Then it moves to assigning C parameter with given value of gamma. After ten iterations it moves to epsilon and assigns optimal epsilon value with given set of [gamma, C] parameters. This gives us in total 30 combinations to check instead of 1000 (10*10*10).

I'd like to import my opt_grid_search object into my projects, like below:

`from own_udf_functions import show_description, opt_grid_search`

The code of the object begins with dynamic statement that creates object that is going to be optimized:

`exec_string = 'opt_object = ' + object_name + '(' + def_params + ')'`

which returns for example:

`opt_object = SVR(kernel = 'rbf')`

However, when I try to use the code in another script as below:

```
opt_grid_search(object_name, params_set, X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test,
                cross_val = 2, def_params = def_params)
```

following error appears:

```
    *File "C:\Users\Marek\Desktop\Python\Github\Kernele\Kaggle Competitions\own-udf- 
   functions\own_udf_functions.py", line 40, in opt_grid_search
    opt_object.fit(X_train,y_train)
    NameError: name 'opt_object' is not defined*
```

It seems that opt_grid_search function didn't execute the following line of code:

`opt_object = SVR(kernel = 'rbf')`

and the object named opt_object wasn't actually created.

I think it has to do with classes, but I would like to ask you to help me better understand what actually happened in this error. I think it is a crucial knowledge that would help me a lot write more 'pythonic' codes instead of defining all of the functions in every single code.

Secondly, please let me know if such optimization makes sense as well or is it needed for the GridSearch to go through all possible combinations.

I tried to keep this description as short as possible, however if you would like to see / need it for the reference, my code is accessible below:

https://github.com/markoo26/own-udf-functions

Comment: So the issue only occurs when you import the script, it works ok if it's part of the same file?

Comment: Exactly. I would like to import the script and use it in another projects and then such error is shown. In case my opt_grid_search object is defined within same script - it works actually fine. Do you have any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is the exec function and the namespace/scope in which it operates. I'm struggling to get my head around this myself but essentially exec() doesn't work for assignment used inside a function in this way. The easiest workaround is to use eval() instead which explcitly returns an object. So end up with something like:

```
exec_string = object_name + '(' + def_params + ')'  
opt_object = eval(exec_string)
```